# "Number the items" or "rank the items"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Can "rank" and "number" be used interchangeably when they mean "put in the order" as in the example below:

"Please, number the items from your favorite to your least favorite."
"Please rank the items from your favorite to your least favorite."

Comment: Numbering the items might just mean assigning random "ID-numbers" to each. ***Ranking*** them definitely means arranging them in some kind of "ranking order" (of preference, price, efficacy, or whatever).

Comment: But numbering may mean the same as ranking that is arranging  items in order?

Comment: Numbering *may* imply "arranging in order", but obviously it doesn't have to. You asked if the two terms are interchangeable, and I was just pointing out that ***in some contexts*** there's a clear-cut distinction. Also note that "ranking" here might not involve assigning any numbers at all - speaker is just requiring a ***list***, presented in a particular order. And "please **number** the items" is at least *somewhat* ambiguous - if there are 10 items, should the most favourite be assigned number 1, or number 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, "number" is a specific way of "ranking" the group.

You could rank the group by using a letter grade, or by "good, neutral, bad" groups. But if you specify to number them, it is clear you expect each to have their own number value.